# How to search value range inside another range in sql

Tags: sql, search, range

I have a form where i enter min price and max price when creating product details. In the product search i have also 2 fields called min and max. So how can i get the result of given range considering the range given when inserting products

Products

```
min  max

10    15
15    30
20    30
```

In the search form i insert min as 5 and max as 16. Which products i will get in the result and whats the best theory for searching considering practical situations.

Comment: Do you want products returned where the product price range overlaps *any* part of the search range, or only where the *whole* product price range is contained within the search range?

Comment: @Mark Bannister that's what i am confused about too. I don't have a exact requirement. What i want is to provide the best solution from the users perspective.

Comment: You have already accepted an answer. I would have suggested seeking clarification from whoever specified that a search range should be available; if clarification was unavailable, add an option so that the user could specify overlapping or entirely contained ranges.

Comment: yep good suggestion to ask from user before they start the search . thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare opposite ends of each range to find products in the overlap:

```
select * from products
where min < $max and max > $min
```

This approach works well for date ranges too.

Comment: So in this case first two rows will be selected.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Solution looks simple and excellent.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from products where min>=5 and max<=16
```

so based on this you will get

Row -> 10, 15

Comment: This solution is perfect. But we will get limited search results and potentially miss products we can buy. thanks

Answer (score 0):

> The **BETWEEN** operator selects a range of data between two values. The values can be *numbers, text, or dates*.

[SQL BETWEEN Operator tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Product
WHERE price
BETWEEN $min AND $max
```